# Black .Blend file?

Tags: blend-files

I made a .Blend file on my PC which opens fine there.

It is saved in my one drive folder which is shared between my PC and my tablet, so all the textures, meshes etc. are saved and shared upon boot of each machine.

However when I open the file on my tablet the whole thing is black and none of the spot lights will work.

All my other files open up on my tablet textured and the way I left it on my PC, How do i fix this guys?

Comment: there is probably no way for anyone to answer this as it is. You are going to have to edit it and add more info, probably the blend file too.

Comment: How do i upload my blend file? Thanks for the speedy reply aswell :)

Comment: You can use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload a file and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: Hard to tell with so little info. Make sure all paths to external data in your blend file use relative paths by going to *File > External Data > Make All Paths Relative* **in your PC, and while it opens fine** . Also make sure your paths are valid in both your PC and your tablet.

Comment: I fixed it guys I just applied a hemi light and it seemed to fix it, Big thanks to all who commented.